# MySQL SELECT Query From Specific Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL table `products`:

```
id, code, name, color
1, 'D555', 'Men T-shirt', ''
2, 'D556', 'Black Men T-shirt', 'D556'
3, 'D557', 'Silver Men T-shirt', 'D556'
4, 'D558', 'Men T-shirt', ''
5, 'D559', 'Black Men T-shirt', 'D559'
6, 'D560', 'White Men T-shirt', 'D559'
```

The column `color` is not empty, if the product have another colors, for example:
The product with code 'D556' is black and it has silver color, too.

I'm using `SELECT * FROM products`, but now I want to SELECT the main products (without the sub-colors), i.e:
`D555, D556, D558, D559`.

- And after that I'll SELECT the sub-colors under the product (since it's about e-store for clothes).

Is it possible with that kind of structure of the table?

Thank you very much for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE color = '' or code = color;
```

You could consider normalizing your table in two tables like the following:

```
products(id, code, name)
alt_products(id, id_products, color)
```

Comment: Hihihi, very clever!! I'll use the first option, because I upload ~300 products every month and it's very hard to optimize for me. Thanks alot for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be useful be this:

```
SELECT `id`, `code`, `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`color` SEPARATOR ', ')  as `colors`
FROM products 
GROUP BY `code`
```